# Function to create percent variables in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a very large census tract dataset for two sets of years. I need to create percent variables for multiple variables (about 75). Here is a subset of the race-ethnicity variables in my dataset:

```
Rows: 146,112
Columns: 13
$ tractid <chr> "01001020100", "01001020100", "01001020200", "01001020200", "01001020300", "01001020300", "01001020400", "01001020400", "01001020500", "01001020…
$ year    <chr> "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", …
$ pop     <dbl> 1808, 1993, 2355, 1959, 3057, 3507, 4403, 3878, 10851, 10596, 3408, 3668, 2744, 3586, 3310, 3196, 10182, 11142, 5844, 6143, 3390, 2527, 3555, 31…
$ racetot <dbl> 1808, 1993, 2355, 1959, 3057, 3507, 4403, 3878, 10851, 10596, 3408, 3668, 2744, 3586, 3310, 3196, 10182, 11142, 5844, 6143, 3390, 2527, 3555, 31…
$ nhtot   <dbl> 1808, 1967, 2304, 1929, 3002, 3274, 4100, 3836, 10684, 10127, 3167, 3503, 2699, 3335, 3032, 3153, 10027, 10927, 5800, 6117, 3364, 2497, 3555, 31…
$ nhwht   <dbl> 1576, 1685, 776, 759, 2359, 2285, 3923, 3495, 8500, 7982, 2885, 2863, 2219, 2658, 2951, 2751, 9027, 9375, 5248, 5250, 2423, 1942, 1110, 1482, 25…
$ nhblk   <dbl> 148, 152, 1465, 1117, 559, 857, 130, 216, 1766, 1929, 430, 693, 474, 730, 275, 436, 976, 1607, 529, 625, 949, 516, 2375, 1660, 768, 378, 284, 22…
$ nhnat   <dbl> 10, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 22, 32, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 21, 0, 0, 0, 28, 63, 3, 2, 0, 23, 112, 171, 27, 75, 74, 245, 98, 70, 32, 19, 0, 7, 32, 28, 0, 0,…
$ nhasian <dbl> 0, 2, 87, 0, 80, 32, 0, 11, 358, 385, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 109, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 21, 0, 8, 0, 0, 43, 243, 244, 267, 0, 6…
$ nhpac   <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0…
$ nhother <dbl> 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 233, 293, 0, 11, 49, 0, 57, 45, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 20, 23, 0, 0, 25, 33, 0, 0, 52, 110, 15, 0, 0, 0, 108, 286, 157, 16, 14…
$ nhtwo   <dbl> 74, 154, 25, 56, 44, 95, 35, 124, 177, 251, 93, 55, 6, 165, 63, 9, 179, 51, 12, 180, 0, 47, 47, 11, 8, 9, 74, 42, 49, 187, 0, 147, 114, 78, 0, 7…
$ hisp    <dbl> 0, 26, 51, 30, 55, 233, 303, 42, 167, 469, 241, 165, 45, 251, 278, 43, 155, 215, 44, 26, 26, 30, 0, 35, 0, 0, 55, 0, 31, 153, 129, 72, 7, 0, 79,…
```

Basically I want to generalize the mutate command below so that I can swap out the new variable name, the numerator, and  the denominator and then return a new column in my data frame for each new variable, just like the line of code below would do.

```
 mutate(phisp = (hisp/racetot)*100)
```

Manually creating percent variables using mutate above would require significant copy + paste and I'm trying to use functions to streamline code. So, I decided to create a function called "percenter" (I know, I'll rename it later):

```
percenter <- function(data, x) {
   
  varname <- paste0("p", x) 
  
  data <- data %>%
    mutate({{varname}} := (x/racetot)*100)
  
}

percents <- percenter(data = percents, x = percents$hisp)
```

However, it throws the following error:

> Error in paste0("p", n) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

I think the problem is that it is applying the paste function to every variable in the dataframe. I only want it to apply to the variable(s) I'm trying to create percents for.

Does anyone else have a better idea on how to do this? Perhaps with vapply or map_df?

The end goal is to create a function that can take as input a vector of variables from a dataframe and iterate over the values in the respective columns of the data frame to create a percent variable based on the input for numerator and denominator.

So as an example for the hispanic variable, I want to create a new variable "phisp" that is equal to (hisp/racetot)*100. The function I wrote above tries to create a new variable name that simply pastes a "p" in front of the variable I use in the numerator. In this subsetted data frame above, I need to create percents for every variable from nhwht:hisp, using racetot as the base. I'll need to turn to educational or income variables next, but I'm trying to work out a function just for the race-ethnicity vars first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few hours after I posted, I figured out a workable solution. Below is the code and the returned data frame:

```
test <- percents %>%
  mutate_at( c("hisp", "nhwht", "nhblk", "racetot"),
    funs(p = (./racetot)*100))


Rows: 146,112
Columns: 17
$ tractid   <chr> "01001020100", "01001020100", "01001020200", "01001020200", "01001020300", "01001020300", "01001020400", "01001020400", "01001020500", "010010…
$ year      <chr> "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019", "2013", "2019"…
$ pop       <dbl> 1808, 1993, 2355, 1959, 3057, 3507, 4403, 3878, 10851, 10596, 3408, 3668, 2744, 3586, 3310, 3196, 10182, 11142, 5844, 6143, 3390, 2527, 3555, …
$ racetot   <dbl> 1808, 1993, 2355, 1959, 3057, 3507, 4403, 3878, 10851, 10596, 3408, 3668, 2744, 3586, 3310, 3196, 10182, 11142, 5844, 6143, 3390, 2527, 3555, …
$ nhtot     <dbl> 1808, 1967, 2304, 1929, 3002, 3274, 4100, 3836, 10684, 10127, 3167, 3503, 2699, 3335, 3032, 3153, 10027, 10927, 5800, 6117, 3364, 2497, 3555, …
$ nhwht     <dbl> 1576, 1685, 776, 759, 2359, 2285, 3923, 3495, 8500, 7982, 2885, 2863, 2219, 2658, 2951, 2751, 9027, 9375, 5248, 5250, 2423, 1942, 1110, 1482, …
$ nhblk     <dbl> 148, 152, 1465, 1117, 559, 857, 130, 216, 1766, 1929, 430, 693, 474, 730, 275, 436, 976, 1607, 529, 625, 949, 516, 2375, 1660, 768, 378, 284, …
$ nhnat     <dbl> 10, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 22, 32, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 21, 0, 0, 0, 28, 63, 3, 2, 0, 23, 112, 171, 27, 75, 74, 245, 98, 70, 32, 19, 0, 7, 32, 28, 0, …
$ nhasian   <dbl> 0, 2, 87, 0, 80, 32, 0, 11, 358, 385, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 109, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 21, 0, 8, 0, 0, 43, 243, 244, 267, 0,…
$ nhpac     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ nhother   <dbl> 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 233, 293, 0, 11, 49, 0, 57, 45, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 20, 23, 0, 0, 25, 33, 0, 0, 52, 110, 15, 0, 0, 0, 108, 286, 157, 16, …
$ nhtwo     <dbl> 74, 154, 25, 56, 44, 95, 35, 124, 177, 251, 93, 55, 6, 165, 63, 9, 179, 51, 12, 180, 0, 47, 47, 11, 8, 9, 74, 42, 49, 187, 0, 147, 114, 78, 0,…
$ hisp      <dbl> 0, 26, 51, 30, 55, 233, 303, 42, 167, 469, 241, 165, 45, 251, 278, 43, 155, 215, 44, 26, 26, 30, 0, 35, 0, 0, 55, 0, 31, 153, 129, 72, 7, 0, 7…
$ hisp_p    <dbl> 0.0000000, 1.3045660, 2.1656051, 1.5313936, 1.7991495, 6.6438551, 6.8816716, 1.0830325, 1.5390287, 4.4261986, 7.0715962, 4.4983642, 1.6399417,…
$ nhwht_p   <dbl> 87.16814, 84.54591, 32.95117, 38.74426, 77.16716, 65.15540, 89.09834, 90.12378, 78.33379, 75.33031, 84.65376, 78.05344, 80.86735, 74.12158, 89…
$ nhblk_p   <dbl> 8.185841, 7.626693, 62.208068, 57.018887, 18.285901, 24.436841, 2.952532, 5.569881, 16.274998, 18.204983, 12.617371, 18.893130, 17.274052, 20.…
$ racetot_p <dbl> 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 10…
```

This uses the `mutate_at` function to create a new variable with suffix "_p" that takes each of the variables in the specified vector and divides them by racetot.

I'd like to put the "p" at the beginning and remove the suffix and adapt this using `across`, but I've spent enough time on this for now. Any tweaks would be greatly appreciated.